# What's the difference between _.map and _.clone with arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects. I need to know the difference between these two lines:

```
var clonedObj = _.map(obj, _.clone);
```

and this:

```
var clonedObj = _.clone(obj);
```

Ultimately both return the same thing. Can anyone explain me the difference please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first snippet with `_.map`, you are applying `_.clone` to *every element* of that array -- mapping each element to a new, cloned object. That means the objects are shallowly cloned one-by-one, thus they do not equal each other meaning they are different objects in memory:

```js
const arr = [
  { foo: 'bar' }
];

console.log(_.map(arr, _.clone)[0] == arr[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

On the other hand, if you clone the just the array, it will shallowly clone the array but the elements *inside the array remain the same*, thus the objects inside the cloned array have the same reference from the original array:

```js
const arr = [
  { foo: 'bar' }
];
console.log(_.clone(arr)[0] == arr[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Internally, the `_.clone` method uses the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) defined in the [HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#structuredclone).

Comment: is clonedObj = obj the same as clonedObj = _.map(obj, _.clone).  Won't  clonedObj in both cases be different objects in memory and not point to the same reference as obj ?

Comment: @ManishPoduval I can't really understand the question? What do you mean exactly? When you clone the array, no matter how its reference changes. The cloned array and the original do not share references.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the official documentation of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

1) **clone**

```
_.clone(object)
```

Clone function is used to create a shallow copy of the object passed.
The array elements are shallowly copied which means the array elements are not duplicated for the new array instead a reference to the existing elements is passed or used in the newly cloned array.

2) **map**

```
_.map(list, iteratee, [context])
```

Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation function (iteratee). The iteratee is passed three arguments: the value, then the index (or key) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the entire list.

```
                 **var clonedObj = _.map(obj, _.clone);**
```

_.map creates new memory location where _.clone function is used to copy shallowly copy elements to the new location.

Effectively, obj is created at a new memory location.

```
                **var clonedObj = _.clone(obj);**
```

In this case, a shallow copied object is returned means reference of items in obj is passed to create new cloned object.
Items in clonedObj contain the reference to items in obj.

### Reference: http://underscorejs.org/